# wordpress theme option in other templates

Tags: theme-options, options

I am using word press theme option panel and using those in my header.php without any issues, code as follows...

```
<?php
    // loading theme options.  used in header.php
    global $options;
    foreach ($options as $value) {
        if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { 
            $$value['id'] = $value['std']; 
        } else { 
            $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); 
        }
    }
?>

<?php echo $aagt_fb_url; ?> //loads fb url
```

But if i use `<?php echo $aagt_fb_url; ?>` in index.php it doesn't work, can you please help me to resolve this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using some custom global theme options, I’d set them in `functions.php`. Then you access them from any template if you declare them `global` first.

```
// functions.php
<?php
$aagt_fb_url = 'foo';
```

-

```
// template file like header.php, index.php, etc.
<?php
global $aagt_fb_url;
echo $aagt_fb_url;
```

Comment: thanks, if i paste options functions to retrieve values in functions.php, it doesn't work after using global $aagt_fb_url;
 echo $aagt_fb_url;

Comment: using `<?php include('options.php'); ?>` at every template file solves my problem.

Comment: Okay, to avoid having to include that file in every template maybe you could make [`$GLOBALS`](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) work for you?